# Does Java support arbitrary size numbers?

Tags: java, integer

Using Java, I am trying to work my way through a list of problems like this:

> Write a program that prints all prime numbers. (Note: if your programming language does not support arbitrary size numbers, printing all primes up to the largest number you can easily represent is fine too.)

Do they mean "all prime numbers up to n"? How can I know whether Java supports arbitrary size numbers or not, and if yes, what is it?

Comment: Java has various math and number classes. The last one I remember is BigInt. Don't know if that's still valid today, though. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html

Comment: I think this question is primarily opinion based. The best way to ask for clarification is from whoever wrote the question, if possible.

Comment: Shouldn't the question title be "Does Java support arbitrary size numbers"?

Answer (score 2):

Java's primitives have well defined ranges. `int`s, for example, range between -2<sup>31</sup> and 2<sup>31</sup>-1. You can see the full details in [Java's tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html). If you want to represent larger integers than the `long` primitive allows (i.e., 2<sup>63</sup>-1), you'll have to resort to using the [`BigInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) class.

Answer (score 2):

A program that printed all primes would be a non-halting program. There are infinitely many primes, so you could run the program forever.

The basic number types in most languages have a defined amount of memory space, and therefore a limited range of numbers they can express. For example, a Java `int` is stored in 4 bytes. That would make the non-halting primes program impossible, since you would eventually get to a prime larger than the largest number you could store.

As well as primitive number types, many languages have arbitrary size number types. The amount of memory they use will grow as you store larger numbers. Java has `BigInteger` for this purpose, while Python just stores all numbers that way by default.

Even these arbitrary-size numbers, though, are eventually limited by the amount of memory the program can access. In reality, *it is impossible to print all the primes*.

What the problem statement you are trying to solve is really saying is that *they don't want you to bother about any of this!* Just use the standard number type in your language. No system is capable of calculating infinitely many primes. What they want you to do is to write the algorithm that *would* calculate infinitely many primes given a system and data type capable of doing so.

Perhaps they could have worded it better. In short: don't worry about it.